# Openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, encriptación

La encriptación me la hace bien pero la desencriptación por alguna razón no, os dejo el código:

```
function sslEncrypt256($url,$key,$iv){ 

    global $_url_contact_id, $__router_url

    $contact_id = $_url_contact_id;
    $str = $contact_id."|".$url;   $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($str, 'aes-256-cbc', 
    $encryption_key,0,$iv);   
    var_dump($encrypted);
    $base64_str = base64_encode($encrypted);
    var_dump($base64_str);
    return $base64_str; 
}

function sslDecrypt256($str,$key,$iv){   

    var_dump($str);   
    $Decode_str = base64_decode($str);   
    var_dump($Decode_str);  
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $decrypt = openssl_encrypt($str,'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key,0,$iv);
    return $decrypt; 
}
```

Comment: Para desencriptar estás usando openssl_encrypt en lugar de openssl_decrypt

Comment: Que despiste más grande xD, tengo que fijarme más; gracias por la ayuda.